# Programmatically change title of window created by storyboard

Tags: storyboard, xcode6, osx-yosemite, xcode-storyboard

In xcode 6.1, how do i programmatically change the title of the window created by storyboard?  This project is for OS X. By default, it is "Window".  I am using OBJ C.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Code in Swift is

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    self.view.window?.title = "joe"
}
```

and in Objective-C it's approximately `self.view.window.title = @"joe";`

It has to be in the `viewDidAppear` because in the `viewDidLoad` it's too early.

---

OT, but to do it via Storyboards it's here:

[image]

Comment: So you don't have to subclass the NSWindow or NSWindowController?

Comment: You don't have to subclass `NSWindow` at all, and you probably should not.

Comment: The code version is in the `viewDidAppear` for the primary view controller.

Comment: How can I access the app window in AppDelegate ?

Answer (score 0):

In the *AppDelegate* context of Apple's common Objective-C Xcode templates for macOS, you can access your main window handle through the following line of code:

```
[[[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainWindow] setTitle:@"Your Title"];
```

Or just use the global constant shorthand for the shared app instance:

```
[[NSApp mainWindow] setTitle:@"Your Title"];
```

These examples first retrieve the app's instance and then get hold of it's main window. Note that if the app’s storyboard or NIB file has not yet finished loading, the app is inactive or hidden, the title might not get applied.

The above assumes you have a Main.storyboard with hierarchy **Window Controller Scene** > Window Controller > Window -- with non-custom Identifier==Automatic and not subclassed this NSWindow.